# Why do we use hexagons in percolation?

Tags: percolation

In some cases, hexagons are used in percolation. Why do we use hexagons in percolation?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143979/

Comment: It's math... like all things, because [coffee](https://goo.gl/images/2bJ1V4)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Site percolation on the triangular lattice (or, equivalently, face percolation on the hexagonal lattice) is the only case for which conformal invariance of percolation at criticality has been [proven](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0764444201019917). This has to do with very special combinatorial properties of the lattice. For a detailed explanation of this, see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.3908) by Vincent Beffara.

Answer (score 11):

The square lattice is [self-dual,](http://web.mit.edu/8.334/www/grades/projects/projects14/PeterFedak/transformation.html) and it is of interest to study also lattices which are not self-dual. The critical probabilities for bond percolation of dual lattices satisfy $p_c=1-p'_c$, so the square lattice must have $p_c=1/2$, and one needs to go to a non-self-dual lattice for a nontrivial value. The triangular lattice is the most widely studied example [with $p_c=2\sin(\pi/18)]$, which is dual to the hexagonal lattice [with $p'_c=1-2\sin(\pi/18)]$.