# Connectivity constant for lattices

Tags: pr.probability, enumerative-combinatorics, statistical-physics

A celebrated result due to Duminil-Copin and Smirnov states that the connectivity constant for the honeycomb lattice is equal to $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$.

My question is the following: apart from the honeycomb lattices, for which lattices is it known *exact* estimates for the connectivity constant (if any)?

Comment: I think the answer is "no other lattices." Also, this is almost the same question as: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408850/particularities-about-the-honeycomb-lattice-for-the-computation-of-connectivity

Comment: See also the Wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connective_constant. I guess there is a known answer for another lattice (the "$(3.12^2)$ lattice," whatever that means) basically because of a reduction to the hexagonal lattice.